# How to detect a failed transaction in neo4j-php-client

Tags: php, neo4j, graphaware

I’m using graphaware/neo4j-php-client 4.5.1 with Neo4j 3.0.4 on PHP 5.6.24.

I don’t understand how to find out whether a transaction has failed.

For example, I try to delete a node that still has relationships. If I run the DELETE in this simple query:

```
$client->run
(
    'MATCH (node { name: {name} }) DELETE node',
    [ 'name' => 'Fred' ]
);
```

… I get this exception, which is the behaviour I expected:

```
[GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Exception\Neo4jException]
  org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.ConstraintViolationTransactionFailureException: 
  Cannot delete node<31>, because it still has relationships. 
  To delete this node, you must first delete its relationships.
```

But when I wrap that same query inside a transaction:

```
$transaction = $client->transaction();

$transaction->push
(
    'MATCH (node { name: {name} }) DELETE node',
    [ 'name' => 'Fred' ]
);

$results = $transaction->commit();

foreach ($results as $result)
{
    $summary = $result->summarize();
    $stats = $summary->updateStatistics();
    printf("Nodes deleted: %d\n", $stats->nodesDeleted());
}

printf("Transaction status: %s\n", $transaction->status());
```

… Neo4j doesn’t delete the node, but I see this (suggesting success) instead of an exception:

```
Nodes deleted: 1
Transaction status: COMMITED
```

Am I missing anything, or is this a bug? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks,

This is actually a bug and I fixed it in https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-php-client/commit/af8f01475a3cf63549498449574eb9c4bb8e7254

The 4.5.3 version including this fix should be available on packagist in a couple of minutes.

Please test and report back.

Comment: Excellent, works as expected with 4.5.3! Thanks for the very fast response and solution!